# PHP, 2 rows into 1

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having trouble getting the correct result set into 1 row because of the way the db is organised.
I use the following SQL:

```
SELECT ord.ID, ord.post_date, ord.post_status, ord.post_type, 
meta.meta_value, term.term_id, term.name, 
SUBSTRING(meta.meta_value,LOCATE('\"id\";i:', meta.meta_value)+7,3) AS prodID,
user.user_email
FROM wp_posts ord
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta ON meta.post_id = ord.ID
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships rel ON ord.ID = rel.object_id 
INNER JOIN wp_terms term on term.term_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_users user ON user.ID = meta.meta_value
WHERE ord.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND (meta.meta_key = '_customer_user' OR meta.meta_key = '_order_items')
AND ord.post_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
AND ord.post_status <> 'trash'
AND term.term_id = 34
ORDER BY `ord`.`ID`  DESC
```

results are:

```
ID Descending   post_date   post_status     post_type   meta_value  term_id     name    prodID  user_email
451     2013-02-02 10:24:00     publish     shop_order  2   34  processing      sales@proxyplayer.co.uk
451     2013-02-02 10:24:00     publish     shop_order  a:1:{i:0;a:10:{s:2:"id";s:3:"339";s:12:"variation_...   34  processing  338     NULL
```

Ideally, I would like to bring back the meta.meta_value as just one row,
so, the meta value 2 would be concatenated with a:1:{i:0;a:10:{s:2:"id";i:338;s:12:"variation_id";...

However, I don't think I can do that in this instance as the meta_value has 2 separate rows in the meta table.

So, I thought I could control it in PHP and get the value 2 and the value 338 out.
But how can I do this in a while loop?

```
while ($squid = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

//1st row

//2nd row

//processing code

}
```

do I put an extra while loop inside that to skip through every 2 rows of the data in the db?
Should I load it into an array and the loop through 2 rows in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that you need to do this in PHP: MySQL doesn't understand PHP's serialized data format.

However, you don't need to skip rows as you say. Create an array outside the loop that will store a $ID -> meta_data relation. I don't exactly know how you want to concatenate them, but look at this for an example.

```
$squArr = array();
while($squid = mysql_fetch_assoc...) // I'm using fetch assoc so I can use the row names as array indices
{
    $rowID = $squid['ID'];
    $rowMeta = $squid['meta_value'];
    $squArr[$rowID][] = $rowMeta;
}
```

Here, this will create an array of meta data for each ID. You could replace the operation in the last line of the while loop with a different operation though.

Comment: The problem is that the meta_value is different for each row though. So, I need to get a results set saying USERID, PRODUCTID or 2, 338

Comment: This accounts for it by putting the values in different array indices. `$squArr[451][0]` will be 2, `$squArr[451][1]` will be that serialized lump.

Comment: Do I need another [] to create more array indexes? I've got the following code: $squArr = array();
while ($squid = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) // I'm using fetch assoc so I can use the row names as array indices
{
    $rowID = $squid['ordID'];
    $rowMeta = $squid['metavalue'];
    $rowprodID = $squid['prodID']; 
    $rowEmail = $squid['email'];
    $squArr[$rowID][] = $rowMeta;
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($squArr); echo '</pre>'; but can only get 0 and 1 in the array

Comment: Doesn't your table use meta_value (not metavalue)? In any case, no, `[]` is the array append operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all rows in an array, you could do something like:

```
$results = array();
while ($squid = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  if (isset($results[$squid['ID']))
  {
    // row with index ID already added, modify existing row
    $results[$squid['ID']]['meta_value'] .= ';' . $squid['meta_value'];
  }
  else
  {
    // add new row, using the ID as the index
    $results[$squid['ID']] = $squid;
  }
}
```

You probably need to put your `processing code` after the loop as the data is not complete in the loop and even if you don't use `meta_value`, you don't want to do everything twice.

Comment: @user1898525 That's why I only modify the `meta_data` if an entry already exists in the `$results` array.